# Set an unique identifier for each window child

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos-sierra

I have to open multiple windows as childs from the main window. I need to set one
unique identifier for each window to show them and then hide them. So I should be able to assign the unique identifier for each window and then using this identifier to call the window to show it then hide.

Looks like windowWithWindowNumber would be a solution, to correlate the id created automatically by the system with my id. What other solution would work? setTag I see it doesn't work for NSWindow

Comment: std::[unoredred_]map?

Comment: Do you keep a reference to the window?

Comment: Yes, sure. Finally I used  windowWithWindowNumber